# Angular 8 Universal Build Failed on SCSS Imports

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am using AngularCLI and an Angular v8.
In regards to Angular Universal, I have encountered an issue where after I run these commands which are the preparatory steps to setup:

```
ng generate universal --clientProject <project_name>

npm install @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader    
npm install @nguniversal/express-engine

Add ModuleMapLoaderModule on AppServerModule
```

or

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject <project_name>
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

When I run `ng build --configuration staging` or even `ng build --prod`, the Build is successful with no errors.

But when I run `ng run app:server:staging` or `ng run app:server:production`, I will encounter an error like below:

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import 'base/colors';

Can't find stylesheet to import.

....
```

My `angular.json` has these following SCSS config:

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },

 ...

 "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
     "includePaths": [
     "src/",
     "src/assets/styles", 
     "node_modules"
    ]
 },
```

Would like to ask If I have missed something or if there's something needed to change?

---

Have tried reinstalling or running these commands but stil no luck:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
npm install node-sass
```

When installing the node-sass, from `"Can't find stylesheet to import."` error message, it is now `"File to import not found or unreadable: base/colors."`

Comment: facing the same issue with scss reference "can't find stylesheet to import"...
Please share if you found any solution.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I faced the same issue "**ERROR in Module build failed... Can't find stylesheet to import**" while running the same command to build ssr "Angular Universal".
for some reason the building process is ignoring "stylePreprocessorOptions" path reference.

**Solution 1**:

change the @import reference to point to the files

example

```
@import "~src/assets/styles/apptheme";
@import "~src/assets/styles/functiontheme";
```

instead of

```
@import "apptheme";
@import "functiontheme";
```

**Solution 2**:

Open angular.json look for "server" >> "options" and add the directory reference

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/assets/styles"
          ]
        }
```

Example:

```
"server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/assets/styles"
          ]
        }
      },....
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Though what have worked for me was without the tilde (~) and just directly specify "@import "src/assets/styles/<file_name>". Still, looking forward that they'll support the direct path instead of specifying their full paths

Comment: Thank you. By adding `stylePreprocessorOptions.includePaths = ['node_modules']` it worked for me.

Comment: Hey! Your change worked for me - but there was no "server" - my path was project -> projectname -> architect -> build -> 

This is also referenced in  the angular configuration section https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-preprocessor-options

Comment: Solution #2 works perfectly for me. I use it because I don't want to change my code a lot. Thank you so much @Elias Sh

Answer (score -3):

If non of solutions provided by [@elias-sh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3292435/elias-sh) not working -> just delete your scss file and recreate it.